# Do Mongoid Gem have option for automatic reconnects?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, rubygems, mongoid, gemspecs

I cannot find an option for automatic reconnection.

If suppose Mongo server is down for a minute and we receive the following error:

```
Mongo::Error::NoServerAvailable : No primary_preferred server is available in cluster:
```

But now the Mongo server is back up again, but all my queries will still give the above-specified error until I manually reconnect.

I checked the reconnect code. Basically, it is reinitialising the Cluster. It would be great if someone could also explain, what is the main purpose of these clusters and why is there a need of reinitialising them.

I checked that when the client is initialised first time the cluster is also initialised at the same time. After that client is used directly, not being initialised in each request same for the cluster.

So to summarise, I need help with two things:

1. Automatic reconnection option with Mongoid gem.
2. What is the use of clusters and why is there a need to reinitialise them again for reconnection?

Answer (score 0):

The MongoDB Ruby Driver (which the Mongoid ODM uses) will rediscover the new cluster primary following a topology change (such as an election or a server going offline).

This discovery is done via a dedicated monitor thread the driver creates for each server. If you're running a Rails application and using a forking web server (such as Puma, Unicorn or Passenger) it's possible that a fork occurred which would orphan the monitor thread.

For this reason it's important to [configure Mongoid for use with a forking server](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/mongoid/8.1/reference/configuration/index.html#usage-with-forking-servers).

Comment: I need the reconnects specifically for Resque. Thanks! I understand the web server part.